# Why am I getting a System.InvalidOperationExpression error when using If Else in C#?

Tags: c#

I have 3 Booleans that I need to have checked: Show, Editable and Clear on Submit. Sometimes the Booleans are already checked and I just want the program to leave them checked (= yes). My code works fine when they are not checked from the start but I get the following error if they are already checked (System.InvalidOperationExpression). The Error occurs on the first if statement.

Here is my code

```
        Page.Control("Editable").Activate();
        if (Page.Control("Editable").Equals(false))
            TestScenario.SaveValueWithDelay(Page.Control("Editable"), true);

        Page.Control("Show").Activate();
        if (Page.Control("Show").Equals(false))
            TestScenario.SaveValueWithDelay(Page.Control("Show"), true);

        Page.Control("Clear on Submit").Activate();
        if (Page.Control("Clear on Submit").Equals(false))
            TestScenario.SaveValueWithDelay(Page.Control("Clear on Submit"), true);
```

Comment: Indicate what line the error is on.

Comment: if Page.Control("whatever") is a bool then there's no need to use an `else if` instead of just `else` as there are only ever two possibilities, true and false. There's also no reason to use Equals as it is already a bool. It seems like you just want to force the values to be true. Why not just assign them as true without checking the values (unless the output of them changing it important for some reason)?

Comment: The failure occurs on the first TestScenario line when the Boolean is already true.  I modified the code above to change the else if as rory.ap suggested but it still fails.

Comment: When I remove the if statements altogether like this: TestScenario.SaveValueWithDelay(Page.Control("Editable"), true); It fails when the bool is already true. When I change the statement to TestScenario.SaveValueWithDelay(Page.Control("Editable"), !true); It fails when the bool is false.

Comment: I don't think the error is in the code you provided. But why are you using such complicated conditions, if you could for examle replace the first one with `Page.Control("Editable")`? Or is this an object instead of a bool? Then I'd still use `Page.Control("Editable") as bool? == true`.

Comment: @MetaColon,  Yes it is an object.  When I tried your last statement, I get the message, cannot convert type to bool? via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion or null type conversion.

Comment: I tried using the next statement, but it did not work either. The end result was that none of my checkboxes were checked.Page.Control("Editable").Activate();
            Page.Control("Editable").Equals(!true);
            Page.Control("Show").Activate();
            Page.Control("Show").Equals(!true);
            Page.Control("Clear on Submit").Activate();
            Page.Control("Clear on Submit").Equals(!true);

Comment: @Blake Thinkgstad.  I am trying to automate some manual tests, but the tests are not isolated, meaning that they do not roll back the data after they run (I plan on doing this in future, but for now, I am just focusing on getting as many tests automated).  In this case, I need to set the 3 booleans, but in other tests that I have they don't need to be set. I thought using the if condition would be the best solution, but I always get a failure when the checkboxes are already checked. I was expecting the code to skip the check if they are already checked , but for some reason it doesn't.

Comment: Then perhaps there is something wrong with the SaveValueWithDelay function if it is failing to set to true when already true

Comment: @Blake Thingstad, I tried running without the SaveValueWithDelay function to see if I get a different result.  None of the Booleans are checked.

Comment: Wouldn't that be expected? Perhaps post the code for SaveValueWithDelay

Comment: @Blake Thingstad Here is the code for SaveValueWithDelay       `code` public static void SaveValueWithDelay(ClientLogicalControl control, object value)
        {
            control.SaveValue(value);
            DelayTiming.SleepDelay(DelayTiming.EntryDelay);
        }

Comment: Here is the code for saveValue `code`         public static void SaveValue(this ClientLogicalControl control, object newValue)
        {
            control.GetRootForm().Session.InvokeInteraction(new SaveValueInteraction(control, newValue));
        }

Comment: All of that seems relatively straight forward and as far as I can see is fine. I think I just realized the issue which was due to the confusing .Equals(false) and .Equals(true). I think your expressions in your if statements are reversed to what they should be. `if (!Page.Control("Editable").Equals(false)) TestScenario.SaveValueWithDelay(Page.Control("Editable"), true);` if the control is true then checking if it equals false would produce false and then you're negating it with `!` making it true. So the control is already true and then you're trying to set it to true.

Comment: So it looks like the only thing I can do at this point is if the Booleans are false before my test runs, I mark them to true and at the end of the test, I mark them all back to false via a cleanup routine at the end.

Comment: I think you can do the same thing you wanted to do at first, just correct your if statements, the first should just be `if (!Page.Control("Editable")) { ... }`. Which actually doesn't make sense. Does the Equals method on those controls access a property of the control and return it's equality? If it does, then `if (Page.Control("Editable").Equals(false) { ... }`

Comment: I've updated the code at the top, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Then the problem is truly with SaveValueWithDelay, unfortunately I can't really help much anymore because I couldn't find much of any information about ClientLogicalControl online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that one of my steps in my unit test, was overwriting the values that I was setting making it difficult for me to debug. So the best approach was to  remove the If condition statement altogether and create a cleanup routine (ie. Disable Interfaces)that clears the Booleans after each run.   Here is the final code:

```
public class Interfaces

{
    internal static void EnableInterfaces(UserContext userContext,  ClientLogicalForm Page)

    {
        Page.Activate();

        Page.Control("Editable").Activate();
        Page.Control("Editable").SaveValue(true);

        Page.Control("Show").Activate();
        Page.Control("Show").SaveValue(true);

        Page.Control("Clear on Submit").Activate();
        Page.Control("Clear on Submit").SaveValue(true);


    }

    internal static void DisableInterfaces(UserContext userContext, ClientLogicalForm Page)

    {
        Page.Activate();

        Page.Control("Editable").Activate();
        Page.Control("Editable").SaveValue(false);

        Page.Control("Show").Activate();
        Page.Control("Show").SaveValue(false);

    }

}
```

Comment: Note: It was not necessary to add  "Clear on Submit" to the DisableInterfaces because I found out that when the Editable bool is unchecked, the Clear on Submit bool is automatically unchecked.